# Custom Email validation for United Kingdom Student Emails xxx@blabla.ac.uk jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress, validation, plugins

I need to have an additional validation on an e-mail field in one of my forms on a WordPress site.

I need to add some regex validation for an input field to ensure that the user inputs a valid university e-mail address. In the UK all student emails end in ".ac.uk"
so for example a valid email should be:

**myname@university.ac.uk**

As well as sending a reply e-mail to that e-mail account (handled by the form) I would require a validation check on submit button click, or on each keyup.

I will be using a plugin for the form but I should be easily able to add the additional jquery validation somewhere in the pluglin script or just in the footer.

Any help would be appreciatted I understand most basic regex but a more detailed explanation would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work out for you

```
^[\w\d]+@[\w\d]+\.ac\.uk$
```

example :

```
var str = 'myname@university.ac.uk'
var res = /^[\w\d]+@[\w\d]+\.ac\.uk$/.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

demo here : http://rubular.com/r/4UeMwiRJe4

Answer (score 0):

@aelor's answer is good, but it will reject some valid university email addresses, e.g. my.name@uni.ac.uk, myname@physics.uni.ac.uk, myname+123@uni.ac.uk. Also, I think `\w` includes `\d`.

Here's a RegEx that should include these cases (loosely based on the always trustworthy [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)):

```
^[\w]+[\w.%+-]*@[\w.-]+\.ac\.uk$
```

Detailed explanation of the RegEx:

1. `^[\w]+`: Starts with one or more letter/number/underscores.
2. `[\w.%+-]*`: Optionally continues with letter/number/underscore/dot/percent/plus/dash.
3. `@[\w.-]+`: Then, an at-sign and one or more letter/number/underscore/dot/dash.
4. `\.ac\.uk$`: Finishes with .ac.uk (dots are escaped).

**Full demo** of form with jQuery validation: http://jsfiddle.net/fs6b9/

Also, it sounds like you do, but for anyone else reading, if validation is important (e.g. you need to restrict sign-up to .ac.uk addresses), you should do it server-side, and any javaScript should purely be to help the user, because it can be ignored.

Comment: Actually an example would help :)

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/fs6b9/. I've updated the answer. Hope that works for you. If you have any problems, feel free to post some code.